# PowerBI DAX - countdistinct based on two columns

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to calculate column 'E' in DAX

1. I wanted to **count distinct** 'B'
   based on 'C' and filter on 'D' = instock.
2. I later want to **sum** column E  -- what is the best way to do this to exclude the duplications

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is split into 2 parts: Go step by step then:

First Step Code:

```
Result =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Product'[size] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( 'Product', 'Product'[product code] ),
    'Product'[stock] = "instock"
)
```

[image: First]

Second Step:

```
Result =
VAR TblSummary =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        VALUES ( 'Product'[product code] ),
        "DISCTotal",
            CALCULATE (
                DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Product'[size] ),
                ALLEXCEPT ( 'Product', 'Product'[product code] ),
                'Product'[stock] = "instock"
            )
    )
RETURN
    SUMX ( TblSummary, [DISCTotal] )
```

[image: Second_Step]

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want a **Calculated Column**?

```
=
VAR ThisProductCode = 'Table'[product code]
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT( 'Table'[size] ),
        FILTER(
            'Table',
            'Table'[product code] = ThisProductCode
                && 'Table'[stock] = "instock"
        )
    )
```

Not sure what you mean by your second request, though.